# Crystal Report on VS2022

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have installed CR13SP33 x86 & x64 runtime and also installed CRforVS6413 and I am able to get crystalReportViewer on ToolBar, create ASP.NET with .net framework 4.8, and dragged the control to the aspx page. but on design view, I am getting the following error, and on execution its blank page, note that my crystal report file already has data in it

[image]

this is my aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" width="1200px" Height="800px"/>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="log4net, Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669E0DDF0BB1AA2A"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

and my C# code to load CRystal report file

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument myReportDocument;
            myReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            myReportDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Serak\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\ConsolidatedBalanceSheet.rpt");
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReportDocument;
            CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have posted a new answer for you again. Sorry that the previous answer didn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config file looks fine.

You must set "Copy Local" to "False", so it doesn't load the wrong DLLs; your \bin folder must have no CR DLLs in it.

Check out [this blog I wrote](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/30/upgrading-a-visual-studio-2008-2019-.net-project-with-the-latest-cr-.net-sdk-packages/) to upgrade your project to VS 2022 (this has a sample web.config that does work).

The problem is that IIS can't find the CR viewer in here, or similar:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_6_81\crystalreportviewers13.Copy this folder into your Project: crystalreportviewers13

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation but its still showing the same error on Designer view and also on debug execution its blank page

Answer (score 0):

Please register the content on your aspx page:

```
< %@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" TagPrefix="CR" %>

< %@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```